# Calling Perl script from Java (JAX-WS in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, perl, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS webservice that receives a string as parameter, calls a Perl script, and returns the string converted to upper case. It is running on Tomcat 8 (localhost on Eclipse).

When I type from the console:

```
curl -X POST --data "mystring=HelloWorld" http://localhost:8080/MyServices/api/generatePath
```

Everything works except for the Perl call. On the debugger I see that line is executed, but apparently nothing happens (not even errors). If I run `perl /home/me/workspace/match.pl` from the console it works perfectly. The path of the match.pl file is correct.

In addition, `process.exitValue()` return 2.

```
@Path("/")
public class MyServices {
    @POST
    @Path("/generatePath")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response generatePathService(
            @FormParam("mystring") String myString) {

        Process process = null;

        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl /home/me/workspace/match.pl --lang en");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return Response.status(200).entity(myString.toUpperCase()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar stuff some time ago. The solution for me was to 'accept' the output of the program. Something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
final InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (is.available() != 0) {
                is.read();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}).start();
```

You should also try to get the error stream with `p.getErrorStream()`. An alternative could be to change your perl program in that way that there is nothing printed to standard out or error out.

Or you call a shell script and redirect the output to dev/null (someting like ´blabla>/dev/null`.

Comment: I just tried it and still doesn't work. The app goes straight to the return before executing the run().

Comment: is there some possibility to 'trace' your perl script? i mean does it run? how far? is there a log file or whatever?

Comment: It's strange. I just replaced match.pl by a hello.pl that does this:
`use strict; use warnings; open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt'); print $fh "My first report generated by perl\n"; close $fh; print "done\n"`. That file report.txt is never created. However, I would say it runs because p.exitvalue() = 0, however, if I change the name hello.pl to hello2.pl (unexistent) it returns 2

Comment: what about calling a shell script? maybe this is better to debug? just an idea...

Comment: Wow, for a dummy helloworld.sh it works. I believe the problem is about permissions. match.pl is creating some files (ideally at the same directory as it is). Is there a way to run this perl command as root? How can I see the output? (I have prints on it)

Comment: Which user is running tomcat? Maybe that user needs more rights. I would recommend adding some debug output to the perl script to see whats the problem. Maybe do some fileExists() after creating it (or whatever the command is called in perl)